# Return fixed number of items from dynamo db query with filter expression

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to retrieve a fixed number(lets take it as 5 for now) of items from a dynamo db table.

This is the code I am using.

```
response = table.query(
                       KeyConditionExpression=Key('pk').eq('goo'),
                       Limit=5,
                       FilterExpression=Attr('goo').eq('bar'))
```

I am getting only 4 items from this. But if I remove FilterExpression, the item count will be 5. So is there any other way to get the fixed number of item even if I am using FilterExpression?

Comment: is it possible that you are getting 4 because the filter conditions match for 4 only ?

Comment: No. If I remove the limit,result will be 11.

Comment: The filter is applied _after_ the limit.

Comment: @Maurice yes, But I am looking for a solution where we can get a fixed number of items even if limit and number of items matching that filter expression are different. like if we send 5 as the limit, we should get 5 items (if there is 5 or more items matching that criteria).

Comment: Unfortunately you're running in a limitation of the service here, DynamoDB can't do that in this combination.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ensuring Dynamo retrieves \*exactly\* n results, given a filter expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214616/ensuring-dynamo-retrieves-exactly-n-results-given-a-filter-expression)

Comment: @LeeHannigan kind of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer I found.

```
paginator = dynamo_db_client.get_paginator('query')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
                        TableName='table_name',
                        KeyConditionExpression='#P=:p',
                        FilterExpression='#T=:t',
                        ExpressionAttributeNames={'#P':'pk','#T':'goo'},
                        ExpressionAttributeValues={
                               ':p': {'S':'goo'},
                               ':t': {'S':'bar'}
                        },
                        PaginationConfig={
                                'MaxItems':5
                        }     
                  )
  
for page in response_iterator:
    print(len(page['Items']))
```

link for paginator doc : [DynamoDB.Paginator.Query](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Paginator.Query)

Comment: Neat, didn't know the paginator hat the `MaxItems` property.

Comment: @Maurice the link you shared helped me to find this answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Filter Expressions are applied **after** items are read from the table in order to reduce the number of records sent over the wire. The Limit is applied during the query operation, i.e. before the filter expression.

If the `Query` read 5 items and only 4 of them match the `FilterExpression` you're getting only 4 items back.

The pragmatic thing would be to remove the limit from the `Query` and apply the limit client-side. The drawback is that you may pay for more Read Capacity Units.

If you want to avoid that you may have to reconsider your datamodel - a generic solution is difficult here.

---

In your *specific* case, you could create a Global Secondary Index with the partition key `pk` and the sort key `goo` (it doesn't have to be unique for GSIs). You can then fire your Query against the GSI with Limit 5 and it will give you what you want. **But:** you pay for the GSI storage + throughput.

---

**Edit**: [This question is pretty much a duplicate except for the Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214616/ensuring-dynamo-retrieves-exactly-n-results-given-a-filter-expression)